# How to issue unix commands from an ios app

Tags: ios, unix

How to issue unix commands inside a ios app? For example, I would like to know if there is any library to load that performs a whois command from the system where the app is installed.

Comment: iOS is not really Unix-like. You can't issue shell commands from your app. Use NSURLConnection to make whois queries.

Comment: iOS is very much Unix-like, but iOS apps are sandboxed and not allowed to spawn new processes.

Comment: There are in fact SSH apps that look just like terminal. So yes you can. This question is very valid.